# Compare two files and output file with mark

Tags: bash, awk, diff

been working on this whole day just cant get it work , too much code i tried from diff awk sed can remember again which code i has tried ,

so here is my problem , i have 2 files (file1 and file2)

```
File1 :

#4 and a row (2)
+1 hello post (5)
10 Years After (6)
21 & Over (8)
50_50 (1)
Almost Christmas (3)
```

---

```
File2:

#4 and a row (2) http://example.com/post1
+1 hello post (5) http://example.com/post2
Not over yet (3) http://example.com/post12
10 Years After (6) http://example.com/post3
Can get it done (2) http://example.com/post24
21 & Over (8) http://example.com/post9
50_50 (1) http://example.com/post7
hear me loud (5) http://example.com/post258
Almost Christmas (3) http://example.com/post5
```

and my questions is how to compare those two files and generate File3 output like this

```
#4 and a row (2) http://example.com/post1
+1 hello post (5) http://example.com/post2
----> Not over yet (3) http://example.com/post12
10 Years After (6) http://example.com/post3
----> Can get it done (2) http://example.com/post24
21 & Over (8) http://example.com/post9
50_50 (1 http://example.com/post7
----> hear me loud (5) http://example.com/post258
Almost Christmas (3) http://example.com/post5
```

**---->** means that this text line is not in file1 .

i hope i've explain good enough and if this possible please do help me since i lack of skill in linux , thank you before! and hope someone will help me sort this out.

~cheers~

**Solution From @RavinderSingh13**

```
awk -v s1="---->" 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=$0;next} {val=$0;sub(/ http.*/,"",val);printf("%s\n",val in a?$0:s1 OFS $0)}' file1 file2
```

and it worked perfectly

Comment: you can use winmerge to compare the files visually but you won't have the output you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -v s1="---->" 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=$0;next} {val=$0;sub(/ http.*/,"",val);printf("%s\n",val in a?$0:s1 OFS $0)}' Input_file1  Input_file2
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -v s1="---->" '
FNR==NR{ a[$0]=$0;next }
{
  val=$0;
  sub(/ http.*/,"",val);
  printf("%s\n",val in a?$0:s1 OFS $0)
}
'  Input_file1   Input_file2
```

Comment: it Worked! thank man you  are awesome! i tried your first awk and it work

Comment: @pdku, not an issue you could do for helpful posts once you get 15, cheers and enjoy learning :)

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$0]; next }
     { 
         r = $0; m = "";
         sub(/ http:.*/, ""); 
         if ($0 in a) delete a[$0]; else m = "----> ";
         print m r 
     }' file1 file2
```

- `r = $0` - variable assigned with current processed record
- `m` - variable aimed to be a `marker`

The output:

```
#4 and a row (2) http://example.com/post1
+1 hello post (5) http://example.com/post2
----> Not over yet (3) http://example.com/post12
10 Years After (6) http://example.com/post3
----> Can get it done (2) http://example.com/post24
21 & Over (8) http://example.com/post9
50_50 (1) http://example.com/post7
----> hear me loud (5) http://example.com/post258
Almost Christmas (3) http://example.com/post5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    keys[$0]
    next
}
{
    key = $0
    sub(/ [^ ]+$/,"",key)
    print (key in keys ? "" : "----> ") $0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
#4 and a row (2) http://example.com/post1
+1 hello post (5) http://example.com/post2
----> Not over yet (3) http://example.com/post12
10 Years After (6) http://example.com/post3
----> Can get it done (2) http://example.com/post24
21 & Over (8) http://example.com/post9
50_50 (1) http://example.com/post7
----> hear me loud (5) http://example.com/post258
Almost Christmas (3) http://example.com/post5
```

Answer (score 0):

How about unified diff? e.g.:

```
diff -u file1 <(awk 'NF--' file2)
```

Output:

```
--- file1   2018-03-26 14:59:49.569347677 +0200
+++ /proc/self/fd/11    2018-03-26 15:01:34.117800718 +0200
@@ -1,6 +1,9 @@
 #4 and a row (2)
 +1 hello post (5)
+Not over yet (3)
 10 Years After (6)
+Can get it done (2)
 21 & Over (8)
 50_50 (1)
+hear me loud (5)
 Almost Christmas (3)
```

Comment: yes this solution also worked man, i wish i can do the vote up for you.